# Regular Expression Challenge: Modify this line of C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am developing a RIA Domain Service that will use a POCO Entity Data Model.  There is some fixup required with the default Domain Service template due to the fact that POCO classes do not implement the `EntityState` property, as does `EntityObject`.

[Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ria-services-and-entity-framework-pocos/) provides the solution:

```
 OLD: if ((customer.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)) 
 NEW: if ((GetEntityState(customer) != EntityState.Detached))
```

The problem is that I may have to regenerate the domain service several times over the course of my development, and there are lots of tables/entities to deal with.

**The Question:**

Can the "OLD" above be replaced with the "NEW" using a regex?  It's a very predictable pattern:

> 1. Find instances of `'.EntityState'`
> 2. Replace with '`GetEntityState([text between ( and .])`'

Comment: Can't you use an extension method and then just add the `()` to make it into a method call?

Comment: did you really mean == becoming != ?

Comment: @MK: No that was copied right out of Julie's article, good catch!

Comment: @CodeInChaos:  The POCO classes do not have base classes, so I'd have to add extension methods to every one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Visual Studio** Find and Replace (and with *Use Regular Expressions* **on**, of course):

Find what:
`if \(\({:i}\.EntityState == EntityState\.Detached\)\)`

Replace with:
`if ((GetEntityState(\1) == EntityState.Detached))`

**Edit**

The OP seems to prefer **Expresso**. In that case it would be like this:

Regular Expression:
`if \(\((\w+)\.EntityState == EntityState\.Detached\)\)`

Replacement String:
`if ((GetEntityState($1) == EntityState.Detached))`

(Also fixed the `!=` typo)

Comment: Works great IF he is using VS, however, other IDE's, mainly Mono, do not support Regular Expressions.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: Well, he certainly needs *some* tool in order to implement regular expression substitution, and if that tool is not available, it will not happen... :) I also made it clear it was valid for VS only. So...?

Answer (score 2):

```
s/(\w+)\.(EntityState)/Get\2(\1)/
```

**edit**: you didn't ask to flip `==` to `!=`, but I'm not sure it should be as that would be the opposite functionality

**edit 2**: also, if you want to do this multiple times on a line potentially, add a `g` at the end

Comment: It appears that the `==` to `!=` would be a typo, otherwise the meaning of the comparison is really changing and that can be a problem.

Comment: @Berin @Daniel: The flip of the logical operator was indeed a typo.  I ran this in Expresso but it didn't seem to do the replace, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ReSharper, you can use its Structured Search and Replace feature for this. Then you'll catch places other than `if` statements -- it will be smart enough to find *any* expression that refers to an `EntityState` property, and transform it to a method call. You can even restrict it to certain classes if you like, though it sounds like that may not be necessary in this case.

1. Go to ReSharper > Find > Search with Pattern
2. In the "Search pattern" box, type: `$obj$.EntityState`
3. Above the right listbox, click "Add Placeholder > Expression". Enter `obj` for the name. Leave "Expression type" blank, or if you want to narrow the search, enter your POCO's type name. Click OK.
4. Click the "Replace" button in the top right. For the "Replace pattern", type: `GetEntityState($obj$)`